# listas enlazadas, ¿como intercambiar punteros a través de funciones?

Tags: c, lista, punteros

La función insertar_final ,recibe un puntero a una lista enlazada lineal y le **agrega valores pasados por valor al final** de  dicha lista. El problema esta cunado la lista pasada tiene cero componentes, es decir, que el puntero a la primer componente de la lista  apunta a NULL. La función deja de trabajar; lo que debería hacer es crear una estructura nueva ponerle el valor correspondiente, ingresar un NULL (en el campo correspondiente,ya que es usado como criterio de finalizacion )para que la lista termine allí ***y hacer que el puntero que apuntaba a lista (que inicialmente-en este caso- apuntaba a NULL) apunte a esta estructura nueva creada dinamicamente***, es esta ultima parte la que creo que escribí mal. Adjunto el código. Gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define cant 3
struct nodo {
             int dato;
             struct nodo* sig;
            };
void mostrar(struct nodo*);
void insertar_final(struct nodo*,int);

main()
{
 int i,d;
 struct nodo *l=NULL;
  printf("Ingrese un valor\t");      //inserto un solo valor al final de la lista
  scanf("%d",&d);
  insertar_final(l,d);
 mostrar(l);
 return 0;
}
void insertar_final(struct nodo *l,int d)
{                                                                                                                                 
 struct nodo *temp;
 temp=(struct nodo*)malloc(sizeof(l));
 temp->dato=d;
 if(l==NULL)
  {
  temp->sig=NULL;
  l=temp;
  return;
  }

 while(l->sig!=NULL)
 {
  l=l->sig;
 }
 l->sig=temp;
 temp->sig=NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## En C TODOS los parámetros se pasan por valor

Los punteros también.

Por lo que cuando ejecutas `insertar_final(l,d);` la función `insertar_final` recibe una **copia** de `l`. Las modificaciones que la función haga al parámetro `l` no afectan a la variable `l` de main.

`l` en `insertar_final` es un puntero que apunta a una zona de memoria reservada con `malloc` los cambios que hagamos en esa zona de memoria sí que afectan a `main` (y a todo el programa). Pues la llamada a una función solo copia los parámetros, no copia las zonas de memoria apuntadas por esos parámetros.

Si queremos que el valor de la variable `l` ubicada en main pueda ser cambiada desde `insertar_final` no podemos pasarle `l`. Lo que debemos hacer es pasarle un puntero a `l` (que sería un puntero a puntero a struct nodo).

Este sería el código de `insertar_final` :

```
void insertar_final(struct nodo **pl,int d)
{
 struct nodo *temp;
 temp=(struct nodo*)malloc(sizeof(*pl));
 temp->dato=d;
 if(*pl==NULL)
  {
  temp->sig=NULL;
  *pl=temp;
  return;
  }

 struct nodo* l = *pl;
 while(l->sig!=NULL)
 {
  l=l->sig;
 }
 l->sig=temp;
 temp->sig=NULL;
}
```

A la cual llamaríamos con

```
insertar_final(&l,d);    // AMPERSAND para pasar un puntero a l
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo resolví haciendo que devuelva un struct nodo en vez de un void.

De esto.

```
void insertar_final(struct nodo *l,int d)
```

A esto.

```
struct nodo* insertar_final(struct nodo *l,int d)
```

y de esto.

```
insertar_final(l,d);
```

a esto.

```
l=insertar_final(l,d);
```

Por algún motivo que desconozco, la función no modificaba el puntero, también no hay que olvidar poner malloc aunque esté en `NULL`.

Código final.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define cant 3
struct nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct nodo* sig;
};
void mostrar(struct nodo*);
struct nodo* insertar_final(struct nodo *l,int d)
{                                                                                                                                 
    struct nodo *temp;
    temp=(struct nodo*)malloc(sizeof(l));
    temp->dato=d;
    temp->sig=NULL;
    if(l==NULL)
    {       
            l=temp;
            return l;
    }
    while(l->sig!=NULL)
    {
            l=l->sig;
    }
    l->sig=temp;
    return l;
}
int main()
{
    int d;
    struct nodo *l=malloc(sizeof(struct nodo*));
    l=NULL;
    printf("%s","Ingrese un valor\t");
    scanf("%i",&d);
    l=insertar_final(l,d);
    printf("%i",l->dato);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En efecto, esta es la otra manera de hacerlo (+1), devolviendo un puntero en vez de usando un puntero a puntero en el parámetro. Puedes leer mi respuesta para saber por qué "la función no modificaba el puntero". Nótese que en el fragmento de código `l=temp; return l;` el asignar algo al parámetro `l`no tiene efectos persistentes fuera de la función; por lo que lo puedes substituir diréctamente por `return temp` y el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Ahora entiendo, y además noté la modificación que hiciste, en vez de cambiar todo el código poniendo paréntesis, hiciste que reciba `pl`, incluso se podría declarar el nodo `l` al principio de la función.

Comment: El cambio que hice lo hice porque el código original estaba mal. Cuando termina la función el `l` de main debe apuntar al principio de la lista y con el código como lo tenía escrito al acabar la función el `l` de main apunta al final de la lista. Por eso en mi función debo usar otra variable distinta de `*pl` para recorrer la lista. Sí, se puede declarar el nodo `l` al principio de la función (de hecho es obligatorio en algunos compiladores).

Comment: Claro si lo había pensado,(que los cambios en la función podían no tenían efecto en main) yo trate de simular un strcpy digamos ya que es un void que intercambia los punteros y sus asignación.
 Pero volviendo al problema  cuando yo ejecutaba el código las lista original, digamos l, me la imprimía lo mas bien, el problema es que no me imprimía la listas pares e impares, usando la misma función para llenar todas las listas, por eso me desconcertaba, pasa que esas listas en principio deben estar vacías ya que podría no haber números pares por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Quisiera aportar una alternativa más a las excelentes respuestas que ha tenido esta interesante pregunta.

Podemos crear una estructura que guarde la información de la lista. Entonces cuando necesitemos pasar la lista como parámetro a una función, usaremos en su lugar dicha estructura:

```c
struct info
{
    struct nodo* primero;
    struct nodo* ultimo;
// Aquí podemos seguir agregando campos según se necesite, por ejemplo para guardar información de:
// longitud de la lista,
// sumatoria de los valores de la lista,
// valor mayor,
// valor menor,
// ...
};
```

Otra ventaja de esta estructura es que permite agregar nodos, tanto al principio como al final de la lista, brindando información extra que permite ahorrar tiempo, por ejemplo si incluímos un campo suma, no sería necesario recorrer toda la lista para saber cuánto es la suma total de los valores de los nodos.

Regresando a las funciones, la copia del parámetro se aplicará sobre el puntero de la estructura, dejando intactos a los campos `primero` y `ultimo`, los cuales podremos usar dentro de las funciones, como si los hubiéramos pasado por referencia.

```c
int inserta_final(struct info* info_l, int dato)    
{    
    // Busca espacio en la memoria para alojar el nodo nuevo.
    struct nodo* nodo_nuevo = (struct nodo*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));

    if (nodo_nuevo == NULL) return ERR;    // Si no hay espacio, entonces retorna error.

    nodo_nuevo->dato = dato;    
    nodo_nuevo->sig = NULL;        

    // Agrega el nuevo nodo al final de la lista.    
    if (info_l->ultimo != NULL)    info_l->ultimo->sig = nodo_nuevo;        

    // Actualiza la información de la lista.    
    info_l->ultimo = nodo_nuevo;    
    if (info_l->primero == NULL) info_l->primero = nodo_nuevo;        

    return OK;    
}
```

El código completo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define    OK    0
#define    ERR   1

struct nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct nodo* sig;
};

struct info
{
    struct nodo* primero;
    struct nodo* ultimo;     
};


struct info* crea_lista()
{
    struct info* info_l = (struct info*)malloc(sizeof(struct info));
    if (info_l == NULL) return NULL;

    info_l->primero = NULL;
    info_l->ultimo = NULL;
    return info_l;
}

int inserta_final(struct info* info_l, int dato)
{
    struct nodo* nodo_nuevo = (struct nodo*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    if (nodo_nuevo == NULL) return ERR;

    nodo_nuevo->dato = dato;
    nodo_nuevo->sig = NULL;

    // Agrega el nuevo nodo al final de la lista.
    if (info_l->ultimo != NULL)    info_l->ultimo->sig = nodo_nuevo;

    // Actualiza la información de la lista.
    info_l->ultimo = nodo_nuevo;
    if (info_l->primero == NULL) info_l->primero = nodo_nuevo;

    return OK;
}

void mostrar(struct info* info_l)
{
    struct nodo* nodo_primero = info_l->primero;
    while(nodo_primero != NULL)
    {
        printf("%i  ->  ", nodo_primero->dato);
        nodo_primero = nodo_primero->sig;
    }
    printf("NULL\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct info* info_lista = crea_lista();


    if (info_lista == NULL)
    {
        printf("Lo siento, no pude crear la lista. Tal vez necesite más memoria.");
        return ERR;
    }

    int d;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nIngrese un valor (0 para terminar)\t");   scanf("%i", &d);

        if (d == 0) break;

        if(inserta_final(info_lista, d) == ERR)
        {
            printf("Lo siento, no pude crear el nodo. Tal vez necesite más memoria.");
            return ERR;
        }
    };

    mostrar(info_lista);

    return OK;
}
```